# Hibernate 5 "is not mapped" exception

Tags: java, hibernate-5.x

Hi **StackOverflow** users!

I'm facing a well know error with Hibernate **5** and I can't resolve the problem with the answers I already found here, in hope you'll find where I'm wrong, could you please tell me if my Hibernate conf is ok?

Here is my pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the cnf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pwd</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://host:port/db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <mapping class="fr.neio.swagdium.beans.PodiumDo"></mapping>
        <mapping class="fr.neio.swagdium.beans.ItemDo"></mapping>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is the class:

```
package fr.neio.swagdium.beans;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "podium")
public class PodiumDo{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
//getters/setters
}
```

The hibernate util:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.configure("/fr/neio/swagdium/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
        try {
            sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And, to end, here is the call:

```
session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query<PodiumDo> query = session.createQuery("FROM PodiumDo where id = :id",PodiumDo.class).setParameter(":id", podiumId);
List<PodiumDo> podiums = query.list();
    if(podiums != null && !podiums.isEmpty()){
        podium = podiums.get(0);
    }
tx.commit();
```

Is there something wrong?
Thank you for reading all this :)

Comment: You obfuscated and hid the most probable reasons for the problem: the package name of your classes, the name and location of your configuration file, and the code used to create the SessionFactory.

Comment: @JBNizet is It ok now?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PodiumDo is not mapped [FROM PodiumDo where id = :id]`

Comment: Why would you need a transaction?

Comment: @KarlNicholas that is irrelevant. And it's always a good idea to have a transaction anyway.

Comment: Children shouldn't play with matches.

Comment: And without looking to the transaction, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: @Laurent-P I don't know if you figure out the answer yet, but I created a test project for your problem and I got it working using a maven project. I tested on a wildfly server.

Comment: Hi @funcoding , I didn't figured it out for now, there was an error on the `addParameter` call but even corrected It don't work.

Comment: @Laurent-P Please, share the whole java class where you trying to query the database. I will share in a moment with you my solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the mistake was in the configuration path, I didn't saw that the configuration file used were misspelled and redirected to another, which only described the database connection informations and no beans.